# Xpath preceding

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

DOM tree

```
<span lightning-radiogroup_radiogroup="" class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
<span lightning-radiogroup_radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">Yes</span></label>
```

My XPath

```
//Label[text()='External']//following::fieldset//span[text()='Yes']
```

UI design

[image]

I want to click the radio button from the above UI, my XPath perfectly located the 'Yes' or 'No'
but unfortunately unable to click the radio button.

From my XPath how can I select the radio button based on the label value (Yes, no)

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML including `//Label[text()='External']`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are selecting the span inside a radio button.

You need to select the radio-button node.
It would be a node similar to this:

```html
<input type="radio" name="name" value="NO" >
<label>
    <span lightning-radiogroup_radiogroup="" class="slds-radio_faux">NO</span>
 </label>

 <input type="radio" name="name2" value="Yes">
 <label>
    <span lightning-radiogroup_radiogroup="" class="slds-form-element__label">Yes</span>
 </label>
```

So you need an XPath like this:

```
//input[@type="radio"]/span[text()="YES"]/preceding::input
```

Comment: Your assumption about HTML-code sample is incorrect as `input` node **cannot** have child/descendant and so XPath won't work

Answer (score 1):

Find the `Yes` text span and then find it's ancestor element here it is `label` then go to its `input` element by `/ancestor::label/input`

```
"//span[contains(text(), 'Yes')]/ancestor::label/input"
```

this is sample HTML:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
//span[.='Yes']/preceding-sibling::span[@class='slds-radio_faux']
```

or (most likely)

```
//span[.='Yes']/preceding::input[@type='radio']
```